Reducing Drafts and Improving Insulation
I’m looking for advice on how to address drafts coming in through a north-facing wall that has a glass entrance. This area tends to feel very cold, especially in the winter, and I want to make it warmer.
The glass entrance includes a door (half glass) and another glass wall extension. At the top of the stairways leading to the bathroom and across the wall, there is another window with double glazed glass (second photo).
I initially thought of buying some thermally insulated curtains for both the window and the downstairs glass.
Can anyone please provide some more suggestions, especially something budget friendly.
I know that in an ideal world I would be adding wall insulation outside however I was hoping to find an interim, cheaper solution until then.
Thank you


the door is single glass ?

Is all of the glass here single-pane?

Check the weather stripping on the door and any windows that open. If it's worn, replace it or add to it. There are many types at your home store. On the downstairs windows, Is that a mail slot? If so, weatherproof it or tape it shut. It will let a lot of cold air into your house. Put a new mailbox outside.

Probably the biggest source of thermal leaking are your glass windows.
A cheep DIY solution would be to cut to size acrylic panels (transparent so you still get day light) and insert over the window glass.
Acrylic is three to eight times more thermally insulating than regular glass windows
